# Create label for work shifts when a shift is spread across midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, case

In SQL Server, I have a table that has a column `StartTime`. From this column I want to create a new one `id` which depends on the datetime value.

| StartTime |
| --- |
| 2023-04-01 07:52:08.000 |
| 2023-04-01 08:41:36.000 |
| 2023-04-01 12:39:22.000 |
| 2023-04-01 21:16:12.000 |
| 2023-04-01 23:16:10.000 |

This new column should take values from the date (yyMMdd) + 001/002 depending on the type of shift:

- Day Shift X (001): Between 8:00 and 20:00 of day X
- Night Shift X (002): Between 20:00 of day X to 8:00 of day X + 1

Below is an example of the columns I want to obtain:

| StartTime | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 07:52:08.000 | 230331002 |
| 2023-04-01 08:41:36.000 | 230401001 |
| 2023-04-01 12:39:22.000 | 230401001 |
| 2023-04-01 21:16:12.000 | 230401002 |
| 2023-04-01 23:16:10.000 | 230401002 |

I was considering a solution with CASE WHEN, but I don't know how to add the part of the day + 1, I only compare the times and it doesn't give me the expected result.

```
SELECT 
    StartTime, 
    (CASE
         WHEN StartTime >= CAST(CONCAT(CONVERT(DATE, [StartTime]), ' ', '08:00:00') AS DATETIME) 
          AND StartTime <= CAST(CONCAT(CONVERT(DATE, [StartTime]), ' ', '20:00:00') AS DATETIME)  
             THEN CONCAT(FORMAT(StartTime, 'yy'),
                         FORMAT(StartTime, 'MM '), 
                         FORMAT(StartTime, 'dd'), '001')
             ELSE CONCAT(FORMAT(StartTime, 'yy'),
                         FORMAT(StartTime, 'MM '),
                         FORMAT(StartTime, 'dd'), '002') 
         END) AS ShiftId
FROM 
    table
```

Does anyone have a solution to handle the night shift and its day + 1 in the condition?

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple:

- If time is less than 8AM use previous date
- If time is between 8AM and 8PM use 001 as suffix else 002

```
SELECT StartTime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ca.date, 12) + ca.suffix
FROM T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) BETWEEN 0 AND  7 THEN StartTime - 1 ELSE StartTime END AS date,
    CASE WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) BETWEEN 8 AND 19 THEN '001' ELSE '002' END AS suffix
) AS ca
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way using `row_number()` to create group of successif StartTimes :

```
with cte as (
  select StartTime, row_number() over (order by case when DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) < 8 then 2 else 1 end, StartTime) as rn
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select StartTime, IIF(DATEPART(HOUR, StartTime) < 8, StartTime - 1, StartTime) as AdjustedTime, 
         max((rn-1)/2) over (order by rn) as grp 
  from cte
)
select StartTime, CONVERT(varchar(6), CONVERT(date, AdjustedTime), 12) 
                  + IIF(DATEPART(HOUR, AdjustedTime) between 8 and 20 , '001', '002') as ID
from cte2
order by StartTime
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/5GLnnHs6)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the time 8 hours back, then check based on that.

Put the adjustment inside a `CROSS APPLY (VALUES` to avoid having to repeat it.

```sql
SELECT
  StartTime,
  NewId =
    CONVERT(varchar(6), CONVERT(date, adjusted), 12) +
    IIF(CAST(adjusted AS time) < '12:00:00', '001', '002')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEADD(hour, -8, StartTime)
) ) v(adjusted);
```

`FORMAT` is slow, so I've used `CONVERT` instead.

If you want this as a number instead, you can use `YEAR` `MONTH` etc and some arithemtic.

```sql
SELECT
  StartTime,
  ID,
  NewId =
    CAST(YEAR(adjusted) AS bigint) * 10000000 +
    MONTH(adjusted) * 100000 +
    DAY(adjusted) * 1000 +
    IIF(CAST(adjusted AS time) < '12:00:00', 1, 2)
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (
    DATEADD(hour, -8, StartTime)
) ) v(adjusted);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/GLhssKp0)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you could achieve this with a couple of `CASE` expressions for this to inspect the time portion of the date and time and then adjust appropriately:

```sql
SELECT V.StartTime,
       CONVERT(varchar(8),DATEADD(DAY, CASE WHEN CONVERT(time,V.StartTime) < '08:00:00' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END,V.StartTime),112) +
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(time,V.StartTime) < '08:00:00' OR CONVERT(time,V.StartTime) >= '20:00:00' THEN '002' ELSE '001' END AS ID
FROM(VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2023-04-01 07:52:08.000')),
           (CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2023-04-01 08:41:36.000')),
           (CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2023-04-01 12:39:22.000')),
           (CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2023-04-01 21:16:12.000')),
           (CONVERT(datetime2(3),'2023-04-01 23:16:10.000')))V(StartTime)
```

Comment: OP only wants yyyy so `CONVERT(varchar(6), whatever, 12)`

Comment: I assume you means wants yy, rather than yyyy. But yeah, I saw that, and thought "That's got to be a 'bug', who *intentionally* uses yy in 2023?" @Charlieface .

Answer (score 0):

To get your result exactly, You can use

```
SELECT
[StartTime],
  CASE WHEN 
  DATEPART(HOUR,[StartTime]) < 8  then FORMAT(DATEADD(day, -1,[StartTime]), 'yyMMdd') + '002'
  WHEN  DATEPART(HOUR,[StartTime]) >=20 then 
  FORMAT([StartTime], 'yyMMdd') + '002'
  ELSE FORMAT([StartTime], 'yyMMdd') + '001'
  END 
  FROM
    
my_table
```

| StartTime | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 07:52:08.000 | 230331002 |
| 2023-04-01 08:41:36.000 | 230401001 |
| 2023-04-01 12:39:22.000 | 230401001 |
| 2023-04-01 21:16:12.000 | 230401002 |
| 2023-04-01 23:16:10.000 | 230401002 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YyWttESc)